# Multiple inserts and selects in one stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to create a procedure that will

A) check to see if TicketNumberInput is in table Tix_number.TicketNumber.

B) if it does exisist, update the record to set UID to @uid and Set the Claimdate to GetDate()

AND ...

C)  INSERT A RECORD INTO ANOTHER TABLE (TRANSACTION LOG TABLE)

If the record does exist, simply add a record to the transaction log with STATUS = 2 (failed).

This is my code so far, but it doesn't seem to have a problem checking the IF statements AND updating the record AND inserting another record.  How do I add many checks into a statement. The Begin End didn't seem to work

```
create procedure [dbo].[UpdateTicketNumber]
@TicketNumberInput uniqueidentifier, 
@UID   int
as 
IF EXISTS(
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM [tixtowin].[dbo].[Tix_Number]
    where @TicketNumberInput = Tix_Number.TicketNumber)
    PRINT 'CORRECT RECORD'

    Update Tix_Number 
    Set Tix_Number.UID = @uid, ClaimDate = GETDATE()
    where TicketNumber = @TicketNumberInput

    /* Success - insert transaction message. Status = 1 */
    INSERT INTO [Tix_Transaction]
    ([Tix_Number],[UID], [status], [Datetime])
    VALUES
    (@TicketNumberInput, @UID, '1', GetDate())

    End
    ELSE

    /* Failed - insert transaction message. Status = 2 */
    INSERT INTO [Tix_Transaction]
    ([Tix_Number],[UID], [status], [Datetime])
    VALUES
    (@TicketNumberInput, @UID, '2', GetDate())

    PRINT 'INCORRECT RECORD'
```

THANK YOU for your help!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got no test as part of your IF.  You need to test, then do something:

```
create procedure [dbo].[UpdateTicketNumber] 
@TicketNumberInput uniqueidentifier,  
@UID   int 

as  
IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL
    FROM [tixtowin].[dbo].[Tix_Number] 
    where @TicketNumberInput = Tix_Number.TicketNumber) 
BEGIN 

    PRINT 'CORRECT RECORD' 

    Update Tix_Number  
    Set Tix_Number.UID = @uid, ClaimDate = GETDATE() 
    where TicketNumber = @TicketNumberInput 

    /* Success - insert transaction message. Status = 1 */ 
    INSERT INTO [Tix_Transaction] 
    ([Tix_Number],[UID], [status], [Datetime]) 
    VALUES 
    (@TicketNumberInput, @UID, '1', GetDate()) 

END 
ELSE 
BEGIN 
    /* Failed - insert transaction message. Status = 2 */ 
    INSERT INTO [Tix_Transaction] 
    ([Tix_Number],[UID], [status], [Datetime]) 
    VALUES 
    (@TicketNumberInput, @UID, '2', GetDate()) 

    PRINT 'INCORRECT RECORD' 
END
```